# Error when trying to create unlocked package version in full sandbox for testing

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package, cicd

When I run the CLI command `force:package:version:create` I get this error:

> Packaging is not enabled on this org. Verify that you are
> authenticated to the desired org and try again.

The org I'm trying to create this package in, is a full sandbox org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create packages and package versions in a Dev Hub-enabled org, which must be a production or Developer Edition org. You cannot create Second Generation Packages in a Sandbox. If you don't want to keep the version, you can later [delete it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_deletion.htm). Note that creating a new version does **not** install the package; no changes are made to your production metadata until you later install the package version.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox!! So does this mean that I have to create the package and its version in my production org (which is my Dev Hub enabled org) and then install that package in a sandbox to test it?

Comment: @Bahman.A That's exactly correct.

Comment: Thanks! One more confusion I have here is that, how can I move this package into my sandbox to install it if it's going to be living in my production org?

Comment: @Bahman.A You don't "move" it, you install it (`force:package:install`). You can install a package in any org you're authenticated with as admin.